# Understanding Figures, Axes and Plots in Matplotlib/PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Help me understand the process of laying down figures on a PyQt widget (and using Matplotlib in general).

When I am doing my own little scripts, I simply do `plot(stuff)` and follow it up with `show()`.

However, this is obviously not good enough with larger applications, or if I wanna use subplots, or raise multiple windows with different results at the same time. I found a really nice tutorial at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/20/matplotlib-with-pyqt-guis/, which illustrated a lot. However, I still don't have the ideas fully clear in my mind.

So, you have a PyQt window. You make a `Canvas` Qt object, and populate it a matplotlib `Fig`. Then you give that figure a pair of `axes`, and finally you tack on all the plots you want onto that pair of axes?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what type of plotting you want to do?  The beautiful thing about pyqt and matplotlib (as well as other plotting libraries) is that they're incredibly flexible-- there's several different ways to go about doing most things. I recommend checking out the crazy number of really specific examples on the matplotlib doc site (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a helpful page [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/leftwich_tut.txt), which provides an overview of the classes in matplotlib.

Essentially, the process is:

- Create a figure which can hold Axes instances (and other artists)
- Create a canvas for the figure to draw itself to
- Create **an** Axes instance, ax, to which plotted lines/patches etc can be added. e.g. `ax.plot(range(10))` or `ax.contourf(array)`

I think your confusion comes from the understanding of what an Axes is. It is "the rectangular area which holds the basic elements" (for rectilinear plots). By default there is only one Axes in a figure, no matter how many times you run the command `plt.plot(range(10))`, although you may decide to use `plt.subplot` to have sub-plots in your figure, in which case you would have many Axes instances in your figure.

HTH,

Comment: The link is died. Sorry.

Comment: A quick google shows that the same page may now be seen at https://github.com/ericliang/matplotlib/blob/master/trunk/scipy06/oo_resources/leftwich_tut.txt